# dpdk-testpmd receives packets but does not send anything

Tags: linux, networking, dpdk

Development setup:

- AMD 3700X on a B450 motherboard
- 2 x intel T210 1Gb NICs (one port each, connected to one another)
- Ubuntu 20.04
- linux kernel 5.6.19-050619-generic
- DPDK version stable-20.11.3

```
$ sudo usertools/dpdk-devbind.py --status
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:06:00.0 'I210 Gigabit Network Connection 1533' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=vfio-pci

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:04:00.0 'I210 Gigabit Network Connection 1533' if=enigb1 drv=igb unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic *Active*
0000:05:00.0 'RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 8168' if=enp5s0 drv=r8169 unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic *Active*
```

One NIC(00:04:00.0) provides traffic (88 packets captured from a live device) in linux mode (nothing to do with DPDK):

```
$sudo tcpreplay -q -p 1000 -l 5 -i enigb1 random_capture_realtek_dec_14.pcapng 2>&1 | grep -v "PF_PACKET\|Warning"
Actual: 440 packets (96555 bytes) sent in 0.440001 seconds
Rated: 219442.6 Bps, 1.75 Mbps, 999.99 pps
Statistics for network device: enigb1
    Successful packets:        440
    Failed packets:            5
    Truncated packets:         0
    Retried packets (ENOBUFS): 0
    Retried packets (EAGAIN):  0
```

The other NIC (00:06:00.0) has dpdk-testpmd running on it:

```
sudo ./build/app/dpdk-testpmd -c 0xf000 -n 2 --huge-dir=/mnt/huge-2M -a 06:00.0 -- --portmask=0x3
EAL: Detected 16 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: 3 hugepages of size 1073741824 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs found for that size
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_igb (8086:1533) device: 0000:06:00.0 (socket 0)
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_0>: n=171456, size=2176, socket=0
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc

Warning! port-topology=paired and odd forward ports number, the last port will pair with itself.

Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
Port 0: 68:05:CA:E3:05:A2
Checking link statuses...
Done
No commandline core given, start packet forwarding
io packet forwarding - ports=1 - cores=1 - streams=1 - NUMA support enabled, MP allocation mode: native
Logical Core 13 (socket 0) forwards packets on 1 streams:
  RX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) -> TX P=0/Q=0 (socket 0) peer=02:00:00:00:00:00

  io packet forwarding packets/burst=32
  nb forwarding cores=1 - nb forwarding ports=1
  port 0: RX queue number: 1 Tx queue number: 1
    Rx offloads=0x0 Tx offloads=0x0
    RX queue: 0
      RX desc=512 - RX free threshold=32
      RX threshold registers: pthresh=0 hthresh=0  wthresh=0
      RX Offloads=0x0
    TX queue: 0
      TX desc=512 - TX free threshold=0
      TX threshold registers: pthresh=8 hthresh=1  wthresh=16
      TX offloads=0x0 - TX RS bit threshold=0
Press enter to exit

Port 0: link state change event

Telling cores to stop...
Waiting for lcores to finish...

  ---------------------- Forward statistics for port 0  ----------------------
  RX-packets: 153            RX-dropped: 287           RX-total: 440
  TX-packets: 0              TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 0
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  +++++++++++++++ Accumulated forward statistics for all ports+++++++++++++++
  RX-packets: 153            RX-dropped: 287           RX-total: 440
  TX-packets: 0              TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 0
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Done.
```

No matter how much packets I pump thru the pipeline, at most 153 packets are processed, the rest is dropped and nothing is sent. I'd guess those 153 packets clog the TX queue in the 00:06:00.0 and that's it.
I tried dpdk-pktgen and it sent nothing as well.

**Note**: the NIC used to send the packets (tcpreplay) is the same model as the one used for dpdk-testpmd.

What am I doing wrong, or what am I not doing (and I should)?

Update 1:

```
testpmd> set promisc all on 
testpmd> start tx_first
io packet forwarding - ports=1 - cores=1 - streams=1 - NUMA support enabled, MP allocation mode: native
(...)
testpmd> show port xstats 0
(...)
rx_good_packets: 153
tx_good_packets: 0
rx_good_bytes: 31003
tx_good_bytes: 0
rx_missed_errors: 287
(...)
rx_total_packets: 440
tx_total_packets: 285
rx_total_bytes: 97035
tx_total_bytes: 17100
tx_size_64_packets: 0
tx_size_65_to_127_packets: 0
tx_size_128_to_255_packets: 0
tx_size_256_to_511_packets: 0
tx_size_512_to_1023_packets: 0
tx_size_1023_to_max_packets: 0
```

```
testpmd> show fwd stats all

  ---------------------- Forward statistics for port 0  ----------------------
  RX-packets: 153            RX-dropped: 287           RX-total: 440
  TX-packets: 0              TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 0
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please execute the commands in the interactive shell as `set promisc all on` and `start tx_first`. Please update the question with the answer

Comment: I am not sure how to read the output - on the one hand, the summary reads non-zero tx packets and tx bytes, yet the size histogram is all zeros.
Since this is a single-port adapter, it's a bit complicated to see if the packets were actually sent. Will rewire the setup and report the findings.

Comment: The stats shared via `show xstats and show stats` are correct. Because `show xstats` states there are around `285` packet send for TX but none of `tx_size_` counters are updated. This means the packet size fed to the NIC is less than 64B. Checking the possible average size by `tx bytes / tx packets` we even get `17100 / 285 = 60B`. Can you please replay with `packet size >= 64B`

Comment: easiest way to test the NIC with testpmd is to use `flowgen` mode. Execute the command in interactive shell as `stop, set fwd flowgen, start, show port stats all, show port xstats all`. Please update the result.